# Java Why does my program require Static variables and is it causing problems?

Tags: java, static

I am trying my hand at using what I have learned to create a Blackjack game, but I seem to be having problems. It seems like everything I do in this project requires me to use static variables, but when I do, I'm not getting the correct answers. What makes java require variables to be static, even when you don't wish to use them, and is that the reason that my results are always wrong? i.e. You and the dealer having the same hand despite .remove(0) being called each time.

```
Card Class:
package cardGames;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Card {

private final Rank rank;
private final Suit suit;

private static final ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();

public enum Rank {

    Two(2), Three(3), Four(4), Five(5), Six(6), Seven(7), Eight(8), Nine(9), Ten(10), Jack(10), Queen(10), King(10), Ace(11);       

    private int rankNum;

    Rank(int value) {

        this.rankNum = value;

    }

    public int getRankIDNum() {

        return this.rankNum;

    }

}

public enum Suit {

    Clubs(0), Diamonds(1), Hearts(2), Spades(3);

    private int suitNum;

    Suit(int value) {

        this.suitNum = value;

    }

    public int getSuitIDNum() {

        return this.suitNum;

    }

}

public Card(Rank rank, Suit suit) {

    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;

}

static {

    for(Suit suit: Suit.values()) {

        for(Rank rank: Rank.values()) {

            deck.add(new Card(rank, suit));

        }       

    }       

}

public Rank getRank() {

    return this.rank;

}

public Suit getSuit() {

    return this.suit;

}

public static ArrayList<Card> createDeck() {

    return new ArrayList<Card>(deck);

}

@Override
public String toString() {

    return rank + " of " + suit;

}   

}
```

And this is the class for my game.

Blackjack Class:

```
package cardGames;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Blackjack {

static ArrayList<Card> deck;
static ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
static ArrayList<Card> dealer = new ArrayList<Card>();

private static int value = 0;
private static int dealerValue = 0;
private static int choice;

private static Scanner play = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    deck = Card.createDeck();
    Collections.shuffle(deck);
    Collections.shuffle(deck);

    playBlackjack();

}

public static void playBlackjack() {

    dealCards();
    showHand();

    showDealer();

    System.out.println("\nThe value of your hand is: " + getValue(hand) + ". What would you like to do?"
            + "\n 1. Hit \t2. Stay \t3. Quit");

    while(play.hasNextInt()) {

        choice = play.nextInt();

        switch(choice) {

        case 1:
            hit();
            break;

        case 2:
            stay();
            break;

        case 3:
            System.exit(0);
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("That was not a valid choice, please choose again.");

        }

    }

}

public static void dealCards() {

    hand.add(deck.get(0));
    deck.remove(0);
    hand.add(deck.get(0));
    deck.remove(0);
    dealer.add(deck.get(0));
    deck.remove(0);
    dealer.add(deck.get(0));
    deck.remove(0);

}

public static void showHand() {

    for(Card card: hand) {

        System.out.println(card.toString());

    }

}

public static int getValue(ArrayList<Card> hand) {

    for(Card card: hand) {

        value += card.getRank().getRankIDNum();

    }

    return value;

}

public static void hit() {

    hand.add(deck.get(0));
    deck.remove(0);

    if(getValue(hand) > 21) {

        System.out.println("You have busted with a score of " + getValue(hand) + "! Game over.");
        System.exit(0);

    } else {

        showHand();
        System.out.println("The current value of your hand is: " + value + ".");

    }

}

public static void stay() {

    System.out.println("You are choosing to stay with a score of " + getValue(hand) + ". Let's see what the dealer gets.\n");

    dealer();

}

public static void dealer() {

    showDealer();

    while(getDealer(dealer) > 17) {

        System.out.println("The dealer is currently sitting at " + getDealer(dealer) + "."
                + "\nThe dealer draws a :" + deck.get(0).toString());

        hitDealer();
        showDealer();

    }

    if(getDealer(dealer) >= 17) {

        System.out.println("The dealer is staying with his " + getDealer(dealer) + ".\n");

        System.out.println("Your Hand: \n");
        showHand();

        System.out.println("\nDealer's Hand: \n");
        showDealer();

        if(getDealer(dealer) > getValue(hand)) {

            System.out.println("They always say, 'Never bet against the house.");

        } else if(getDealer(dealer) == getValue(hand)) {

            System.out.println("It's a push, you have the same score as the dealer.");

        } else {

            System.out.println("Your " + getValue(hand) + " beat the dealer's " + getDealer(dealer) + ". Congratulations!");

        }

        System.out.println("Would you like to play again? (1. Yes \t2. No)");

        choice = play.nextInt();

        switch(choice) {

        case 1:
            new Blackjack();
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("\nThanks for playing.");
            System.exit(0);
            break;

        default: 
            System.out.println("That was unintelligible, you must have had a little too much Chardonnay. We're calling you a cab.");
            System.exit(0);

        }
    }   

}

public static void showDealer() {

    for(Card card: hand) {

        System.out.println(card.toString());

    }

    System.out.println("\n");

}

public static int getDealer(ArrayList<Card> dealer) {

    for(Card card: dealer) {

        dealerValue += card.getRank().getRankIDNum();

    }

    return dealerValue;

}

public static void hitDealer() {

    dealer.add(deck.get(0));
    deck.remove(0);

}

}
```

Comment: It requires static variables because you're doing everything from static methods.

Comment: Make `main()` create an *instance* of `Blackjack` and have it call `play()` on that instance. That should get you on your way to change your static methods to instance methods.

Comment: On a side note: any particular reason why you're shuffling the deck *twice*? You're not trusting the (pseudo-)randomness?

Comment: Yes, that's the only reason I shuffle twice, lol. :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing all your logic in a static main method and thats why its asking for all the variables to be static.

Abstract out the entire logic of blackjack in a different class and use that class instance to do all your required tasks.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a different class, just make `Blackjack.main()` create an *instance* of `Blackjack`.

Comment: It would be easier to move out the main method. Or use the `new` key word in static method.

Comment: It all started because of this line. It says I cannot make a static reference to a non-static method. How can I call this otherwise: deck = Card.createDeck();

Answer (score 1):

Well, you brought it on yourself.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    deck = Card.createDeck();
    Collections.shuffle(deck);
    Collections.shuffle(deck);

    playBlackjack();

}
```

The `createDeck()` method. Does it need to be static? the `playBlackjack()` method. Does it need to be static? You need to work with objects by using the `new` operator. 
It is asking you to make everything static because you arent working with objects. the main method should be something like this.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Card cardDeck = new Card();
         ....  //  your code here     
        card.playBlackjack();

    }
```

Comment: According to Eclipse I can't use Card cardDeck = new Card(); because I don't have an empty Constructor, but if I make one, then my class doesn't have the rank and suit. I don't understand how to make that work.

Comment: yes, i understand. Create a parameterized constructor and pass in the values that you need to setup the Object. This is the dependency that you are injecting in your object. So, for a Card object to be created, you need the `rank` and `suit`. This is exactly why people use DI or IOC frameworks like `Spring`